# One way permutation and its inverse

Tags: one-way-function, permutation

Is the following statement correct?
Let $F$ be a OWP. Then the inverse $F^{-1}$ of $F$ is also a OWP.

Answer (score 3):

In general, unless the OWP also happens to be a trapdoor permutation, there is no way to efficiently evaluate the inverse. So, no.

Comment: Thanks for answering, how can i proof like these statements?

Comment: Well, if the inverse were efficiently publicly computable, then the permutation $F$ would not be one-way. If it were only computable given some kind of additional information then $F$ would be a TDP.